# 220 breaker will not turn off

Tags: circuit-breaker

our range is on a 220 breaker. We lost power for approx 75 minutes. When the power came back on the oven door was locked.  Our instructions were to turn off the breaker, then turn back on and oven door should be unlocked. When the breaker is turned off the oven still has power, we left it off for 45 minutes and it still had power. Does the breaker need to be replaced?

Comment: Are you sure you are on the correct breaker? Can you unplug the stove? If you are on the correct breaker this would be a serious problem normally associated with federal pacific stab lock panels, if this is the brand a new panel is in order.

Comment: @EdBeal that's the first place I went, "stab-lok".  It's a brand of panel that cheated its way through its UL listing (think Volkswagen diesels)... the company said "we cheated, but it's not unsafe enough to warrant broad replacement" and the FTC dropped it because they went bankrupt, so no money to recover.  But they lied, they are unsafe.

Comment: @Harper -- CPSC, not FTC, and the *Kaiser Aluminum* case had an impact as well

Comment: Can you post a photo of your breaker box please?

Comment: I hope the op posts photos, stab locks do have a high percentage of failures to open that is much higher with double pole breakers, after finding the buss damaged on one of these I now won't work on them except to replace them.